# I'm trying to update angular from 9 to 11. How do I resolve dependency issues?

Tags: angular, exception, npm, dependencies, conflict

I'm trying to update a project from angular 9 to 11. Following Angular Update Guide, I should run `ng add @angular/localize` but I get following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: veafront@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: tslib@2.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/tslib
npm ERR!   tslib@"^2.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer tslib@"^1.10.0" from @angular/compiler@9.1.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~9.1.11" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\kacpe\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kacpe\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-24T13_18_04_703Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
See "C:\Users\kacpe\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-31LdX5\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I tried to use `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps` but it did not help. How do I resolve this issue?